# Querying Two Tables in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can someone please help me, I have to compare two tables, my managers want to see a comparison between two tables in an Access database. Both tables contain IP phones, their type, MAC and the site id they are assigned to. what my managers want is to view this data in one form. i know i can do this with two sub forms but it will be much better if i can do it with one sql statement as i know it can be done but i am just to stupid to do it. what i need is three columns, column 1 = handset type, column 2= table 1 count, column 3= table 2 count:

```
Handset Type |TABLE 1 COUNT| TABLE 2 COUNT|
CISCO7911    | 100         | 50
CISCO7942    | 100         | 50
```

I currently have this which works for one two of the columns by only querying one table but how would i add the last column, i have tried UNION but this adds the data to extra rows instead of another column.

```
SELECT tbl_handsets.handset_type,
    Count(IIf(handset_site_id='12345',1,Null)) AS myCompany_Number
FROM tbl_Handsets
GROUP BY tbl_handsets.handset_type
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're telling us this query returns the data you want for `Handset Type` and `TABLE 1 COUNT` ...

```
SELECT
    handset_type,
    Count(IIf(handset_site_id='12345',1,Null)) AS myCompany_Number
FROM tbl_Handsets
GROUP BY handset_type
```

... and substituting `tbl_Accenture` for `tbl_Handsets` as the `FROM` returns what you want for `Handset Type` and `TABLE 2 COUNT`, then build a query which uses both of those as subqueries and join the two of them together.

```
SELECT
    t1.handset_type,
    t1.myCompany_Number AS [TABLE 1 COUNT],
    t2.myCompany_Number AS [TABLE 2 COUNT]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            handset_type,
            Count(IIf(handset_site_id='12345',1,Null))
                AS myCompany_Number
        FROM tbl_Handsets
        GROUP BY handset_type
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            handset_type,
            Count(IIf(handset_site_id='12345',1,Null))
                AS myCompany_Number
        FROM tbl_Accenture
        GROUP BY handset_type
    ) AS t2
    ON t1.handset_type = t2.handset_type
```

Comment: Fantastic you are my hero!!!!
thank you so much that is exactly what I needed, great job!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Steven.  If subqueries are unfamiliar to you, have a look at Allen Browne's pages: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html

Comment: Thanks i will have a look at this, i usually only stick to VBA but recently i have been tasked to work with SQL

Answer (score 0):

Might be It can help, but I dint test it.

If your tables have a column which represent the handset_type_id then query will change to

```
SELECT tbl_handsets.handset_type,
    COUNT(*) AS Table1_Count,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Accenture 
        WHERE tbl_Accenture.handset_type = tbl_handsets.handset_type
        AND  tbl_Accenture.handset_site_id  = '15017' ) 
    AS Table2_Count  
FROM tbl_Handsets
Where tbl_handsets.handset_site_id = '15017'
GROUP BY tbl_handsets.handset_type
```

Comment: check updates, I missed opening "(" before both select, try it.

Comment: Hi, it works now but its not giving me the result i want, i need to divide the results by the handset type.

SELECT  tbl_Handsets.handset_type, 
(SELECT COUNT(IIf(handset_site_id='15017',1,Null)) FROM tbl_Handsets) AS Table1_Count, 
(SELECT COUNT(IIf(handset_site_id='15017',1,Null)) FROM tbl_Accenture) AS Table2_Count
FROM tbl_Handsets
GROUP BY tbl_handsets.handset_type

Comment: Does your tables have any column for handset_type_id or not? will you update your question, with you tables schema?

Comment: tbl_one {
ID
Handset_Type - string
handset_site_id - string
}

tbl_two
{
ID 
Mac_Address - string
Handset_Type - string
Handset_Site_Id - string
... more fields that are not important for this
}

Comment: Hi thanks for trying but this still is not doing what i want.....

i need three columns, column 1 = handset type / column 2 = count of tbl_one where site id = 123 / column 3 = count of tbl_two where site id = 123

Comment: I should include the condition in subquery also, check updated answer.

Comment: It still does not work ... i dont get this line .... WHERE tbl_handsets.handset_type  = tbl_handsets.handset_type  why are we comparing the same data

Comment: this is not same ---  WHERE tbl_one.handset_type = tbl_handsets.handset_type. I am comparing here with tbl_one's column to tbl_handsets's column.

Comment: there are two tables

tbl_one = tbl_handsets 

tbl_two = tbl_Accenture